# winform app webbrowser error changes are not allowed while code is running

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

i am facing an issue in winform app, i am using webbrowser control. At one point i am using for loop and in the loop i have to invoke the Enter button event programatically. It is something like below:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    htmlElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(PagerTxtBoxID);
    htmlElement.InnerText = i.ToString();
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");

}
```

now every time at SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}"); the page should gets refreshed with new values (inside webbrowser control).

However it is not working and the page is not refreshing and when i am trying ti debug, it shows changes are not allowed while code is running.

Requesting you folks to please guide me from here.

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys.Send(...) actually send the keyboard signals as when you are hitting keys on whatever is focused now. If you are on debug, it probably tries to send enter key to visual studio, modifying the C# code. You have to figure out another way of interacting with the webbrowser. One method is to programatically click a html button.